# Dividing large numbers in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, decimal, precision

I am working with numbers of 18 decimals, I have decided to save the number as a "NUMERIC (36)" in database

Now I want to present it by doing the following division

```
select (5032345678912345678::decimal  / power(10, 18)::decimal )::decimal(36,18)
```

result
5.032345678912345700

expected result
5.032345678912345678

It works if I use a precision of 16 decimals

```
select (50323456789123456::decimal  / power(10, 16)::decimal )::decimal(36,16)
```

result 5.0323456789123456

**Any idea how to work with 18 decimals without losing information?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a constant typed as `decimal(38,18)`:

```
select 5032345678912345678::decimal / 1000000000000000000::decimal(38,18);

       ?column?       
----------------------
 5.032345678912345678
(1 row)
```

A constant should be a bit faster. However the same cast should work for `power(10,18)` as well.

Comment: Thanks, I had concentrated so much on the use of the pow () function, because I keep the precision in database that does not probe with a constant. regards